# What's happens to credit in the non-Organizer account when you turn on Family Sharing?

Tags: apple-id, itunes-store, family-sharing

I, my wife and my three kids all have apple devices and IDs. However, some of my kids have credit balances from gift cards.

If I turn on Apple Sharing, can those gift balances still be spent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Gift balances are preserved.

In fact, I use a gift balance to avoid charging the family organizer for my primary Apple ID. I want to pay for my apps and be part of the family to share apps and calendars and reminders easily.

This lets me use my Credit Card to buy gift cards (usually at a substantial discount from Costco) and/or use Apple Pay and Passbook to load my store credit at Apple Retail Stores without needing a physical gift card at all.

Comment: so, the gift balance isn't shared? But, the purchase made is shared?

Comment: Yes. Each account maintains their separate gift balance if any. Any gift card credits accumulate on each sub-account. All credit card billing gets removed from all but the organizer account. All purchases that don't pull from credit (for a variety of reasons) go against that one card.

Comment: @bmike You mean to say, that the "non-organiser" purchases (via gift card) are shared with others?

Comment: Yes - exactly @Codevalley I need to update this answer, you can even load your gift card yourself now in the wallet on iPhone. All purchased apps share regardless of which payment added it to any family account.

Comment: It seems to work differently for me. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367997/family-sharing-and-non-organizers-previous-purchases