# Is there a way to charge a purchase to the account owners credit card rather than the organizer accounts credit card?

Tags: family-sharing

With family sharing the docs say ALL purchases are charged to the organizers credit card.

Is there a way to charge a purchase to the account owners credit card rather than the organizer accounts credit card?

Comment: maybe try http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/186672/85275 as a workaround

Answer (score 1):

For an "adult" in the family to use their own credit card they would need to be removed.

> [Ref: HT201079](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201079) Section: near bottom of page, above "*Age may vary by country".

The "adult" could make purchases using gift cards redeemed to their personal iTunes ID, though this won't stop subscriptions or gift purchasing from being charged to the "organizer".

> [Ref: HT201079](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201079) Section: First paragraph and "Making Purchases".

It's not possible to remove the credit card from the "organizer" account completely, but you could update the "organizer" card to the desired card, then change it back after the purchase. This would only work for non-subscription content. If subscription content is purchased and the card is changed after, the card on the "organizer" account at the time of renewal would be charged. The renewal may also be interrupted.

Do be careful to prevent any unwanted purchases to the card on the "organizer" account, from any other family members including the "organizer", during any temporary changes.

> [Ref: HT203905](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203905) Section: bottom of page "If your part of Family Sharing"

- [Family purchases and payments](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201079)
- [Reasons for not seeing "none" in iTunes Store payment options](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203905)

Accepted payment card type on "organizer" account may vary depending on 'child' account being present and any accounts with Ask to Buy enabled.

Comment: Thanks. The other adult not being in the family defeats the purpose of sharing, which allows app/music sharing. We worked it out with the gift card work around.