# Family sharing and non-organizer's previous purchases

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, ios-appstore, family-sharing

So, my wife has been using her iPad for a while, I have been using it for a while. Now, we added both of us to a family account (with me being organizer). And, while I purchased an app which my wife had already purchased (before we set up the sharing), my assumption was that I wouldn't pay for it. But to my surprise, my card got charged. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Have you made sure the app is eligible for [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203046)?  Also, you wife had to accept the invitation to join the Family, it's not automatic.

Comment: Yes to both. But when I open my App Store Account > Family Sharing, it doesn't show my wife in that (Family purchases section)
While when I do the same on my wife's device it shows my account in (Family purchases) section

Comment: In fact as an organizer, I am not able to see anyone else's purchases. While each member can see theirs+organizer's.

Comment: Do you have more than one Apple ID yourself? I have 2 & it took me ages to figure out which one I had to invite myself to, to get it all to work.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your Family Sharing screen?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you went into the App Store > Searched for the App > Installed. Rather, with Family Sharing, you would want to navigate to the App Store > Tap your icon in the upper right corner > Purchased > from here you should see each member of the Family. Tap into one of them to view their purchases & ultimately download free of charge. When it is being downloaded free of charge you will see the iCloud icon with an arrow pointing down.

Hope that helps!